# How to Reduce Space in DIV using Using Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, spacing

In this Fiddle, how can I reduce the space between the individual content(the 1,2,3,4) and its border. I'm kinda new to Flexbox, and I don't know if there is an easy fix to this.

Here is what I mean(more specifically)

https://ibb.co/z73dJ4m

versus

https://ibb.co/pzwhVB5

Thanks

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ragingfury/0nrq94jt/2/

```css
.a{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  text-align:center;
}
.b{
flex:40%;
margin:20px;
border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">

  <div class="b">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    4
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: remove  `margin: 20px;` from `.b`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I reedited the post

Comment: I am not sure what you want ? Those images does not help at all. You want reduce width of each div `.b`

Comment: Exactly, but setting width:50% to each ```.b``` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Nor does changing the padding of the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `space-evenly` and setting some width on your `.b` instead of `flex:40%`

I hope that's what you wanted.

Here is working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9xd2hna5/

```css
.first,
.second {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.b {
  width: 15em;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">

  <div class="first">
    <div class="b">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="b">
      2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="second">

    <div class="b">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="b">
      4
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is just what I wanted!

Comment: @BobStewart glad to hear that. Would you mind accepting my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as the solution and upvote please thanks.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you asking for this but if you want to reduce space between (1,2,3,4) then, Try adjusting the margin property in class b(i,e .b).

For example if you set margin to less than the current value then it will reduce the space between (1,2,3,4).

Similarly if you want to reduce its border just set border 1px solid blue to something less like border 0.5 solid blue.

And also if you want to reduce the space within the box.
i mean space between border and the item inside the box then use **padding** property in the class b i.e, .b.

Hope this helps you. If you have any question please ask.

Happy coding. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is what I mean though:

https://ibb.co/z73dJ4m

Versus

https://ibb.co/pzwhVB5

The items are still evenly spaced, just not stretched so much across the screen